# Windows Form Web Control Frozen

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, webforms, web-controls

I'm using C# to make a windows form application. I have some Javascript that interacts with the C# to pass a string of JSON data when triggered by a certain user event. However, upon a random number of user events triggering this communication, the Web Control freezes completely.

**Javascript**

```
function userScroll() {

    var range = timeline.getVisibleChartRange();
    var left = range.start.getTime();
    var right = range.end.getTime();

    // Gets event data from C#
    var jsonData = window.external.HandleScroll(left, right);
}
```

This is bound to three events on a particular div, these events being `mousedown`, `mouseup`, and `wheel`.

**C#**

```
public string HandleScroll(long scLeft, long scRight)
{
    string jsonData;        

    // some math on inputs
    // generating JSON

    return jsonData;
}
```

Why is my web control freezing?

Comment: Is debugger pointing to anywhere? maybe use some try/catch blocks and put some breakpoints to see?

Comment: Debugger gives me nothing because nothing is running, it simply returns the string, but the page in the web control is unresponsive.

Comment: The standard webcontroller in winforms is a bit tricky. maybe you can try an alternative like https://code.google.com/p/geckofx/

Comment: Also make sure you are using different threads to interact with the webcontrol

Comment: @SaeidYazdani It's a single-thread application

Comment: I think my event listener is hijacking the event from the 3rd party tool listening to the same event.

Comment: That might be the problem. I would check if using a different thread for handling the webcontrol would make any change